# Disable inheritance from parent

Tags: permissions, groups, inheritance

Where i disable inheritance from parent. I want delete several groups. 
Where i delete this groups[image]

Where i disable inheritance and add users from root site -> user goes in sites where this group existing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly then,

If you click **Delete Unique permissions**, then all the permissions you've set uniquely will be deleted.

After breaking the inheritance, if you want to remove the groups then select the names of the groups/users and click **Remove User permissions**. The group/users (you delete here) will not be deleted but their permissions from particular site/list will be deleted.

If you want to add users/groups then click **Grant Permissions** and add users/groups and set desired permissions.